# Android Studio 3 Create New Project Error . Gradle sync faile , Unable to resolve dependency

Tags: android-studio

i have problem with creating new project in android studio 3 
when i create new project and select empty activity this errors comes up 
Gradle sync failed
unresolved android dependecies .

i tried uncheck work offline for gradle . it download any requiered file  and then i click invalidate caches / restart  but it dos not work for me .

i had not any problem with android studio .  this errors comes up after i delete my ex project ( without closing the project ) and tried to create new project

here is an screen shot of my android studio .

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LazXxmVO2hE2_YmA5ub8rW4JPjNd8iWL/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i keep trying and finally sucseed to solve the problem 
By opening SDK Manager and update build tools to the latest version 
but still Im wonder that why my problem solved by doing this . 
im new in Android Coding so can anyone explane plz ?